# Compute index of Fibonacci number mod prime

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, cryptography

> Given a prime $p$ and a Fibonacci number $(F_n \bmod{p})$, how fast can you find $n$?

---

- Obvious Answers

  - If you are given $F_n$ without reducing $(\bmod{p})$ [you can solve the problem in O(log n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162780/an-inverse-fibonacci-algorithm).
  - The "bruteforce" solution is as hard as computing the discrete logarithm in $\mathbb{F}_p$.
- Further Assumptions

  - We can assume that $n$ is smaller than the Pisano period.
  - We can assume that $x^2-x-1$ has roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ and the Pisano period is known.
  - We can assume that $F_{n+1}$ is given, too.
- We can reduce the problem to any of the following decision problems:

  - Given that $n$ is even, is $n$ divisible by $4$?
  - Is $n<\frac{p}{2}$ ?

Comment: Pisano Period might help. It suggests that if $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{10}$ then $x^2-x+1$ has roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$, but if $p\equiv \pm 3\pmod{10}$, then it does not. [Wikipedia for Pisano Period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) In general, this is known to be periodic, but not necessarily easier than the discrete logarithm (depending on calculation methods).

Comment: Assuming $x^2-x+1$ does have roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ and I know the corresponding Pisano period, how does that help to calculate the index of $(F_n \mod{p})$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure it does. It was only an idea that might help, which is why I put it in the comments and not as an answer.

Comment: I’m going to have to vote to close this as *too broad* — not because there’s anything wrong with your specific questions, but because there are too many of them. Please, **one question per post**.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor let me rephrase it

Comment: Both the Pisano period and the discrete logarithm will only tell you what $n$ is modulo $p-1$ respectively modulo Pisano period. They cannot tell you what $n$ is.

Comment: @N.S. yes, of course I am interested in $(n\mod{p-1})$ respectively $(n\mod{\pi(p)})$ where the Pisano period $\pi(p)$ divides $p-1$ since $x^2-x+1$ has roots in $F_p$.

Comment: @N.S. actually even knowing only if 4 divides $n$ would solve my problem

Comment: It is trivial to decide if $n$ is odd or even. Deciding if $n$ is multiple of $4$ is probably tricky without discrete log.

Comment: @mathemathemathe Perfect

Comment: Since $Z = \begin{bmatrix} F_{n+1} & F_{n} \\ F_{n} & F_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = M^n$ with $M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, I think you can just diagonalize $M = QDQ^{-1} \pmod p$ and then it becomes a problem of solving $Q^{-1}ZQ = D^n \pmod p$ with $D$ diagonal which is the discrete log problem.

Comment: @DanielV yes, but is there any faster solution?

Comment: I haven't thought all the details through, but to me @DanielV's point suggests that the question is more or less equivalent to solving an instance of the discrete logarithm problem with either root of $x^2-x-1$ as a base?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I thought so too, but since $D$ (and $Q$) depends on $p$ it is possible that it is a simpler strict subset of the discrete log problem.  I'm not sure.

Comment: >> _it is possible that it is a simpler strict subset of the discrete log problem_


@DanielV this is actually the core of my question. I'd guess it is as hard as computing the discrete log but I wonder if there isn't any structure in the Fibonacci numbers which you could exploit to solve this problem faster.

Comment: @mathemathemathe I think you should start by looking at an explicit formula for $D$ and $Q^{-1}ZQ$.  I really don't want to compute all that and it is your problem....

Comment: What makes you think you can find $n$?